# Design dilemma with relation between entities and 'global'

Tags: design

I have the following dilemma with designing a piece of software.

1. How can I design a relation between the follwing entities so that a configuration rule can be global or apply to a building / room or a combination of buildings / rooms?
2. How should the result data

I think I should use the following entities:

```
ConfigurationRule {
    id: number; 
    key: string;
    value: any;
}

Global: {
    building: Building[]; 
}

Building: {
    id: number; 
    name: string;
    rooms: Room[];
    stories: number;
    builddate: date:
}

Room: {
    id: number; 
    name: string;
    dimensions: {
        height: number;
        width: number;
        depth: number;
    }
}
```

We have the following requirements:

- a building consists of many rooms (one-to-many)
- a configuration rule may be applied to one or more buildings (one-to-many)
- a configuration rule may be global and will apply to all buildings and rooms in the building
- a building configuration rule overrules a global rule
- a room configuration rule overrules a building rule

Sample data

```
configurationRules = [  
    { id: 1, key: 'hasPower', value: "220Volts" }  
    { id: 2, key: 'hasInternet', value: false },  
    { id: 3, key: 'hasInternet', value: 'fiber' },  
    { id: 4, key: 'hasInternet', value: 'dsl' },  
    { id: 5, key: 'hasInternet', value: 'sattelite' },  
    { id: 6, key: 'plotter', value: true },  
]

Buildings = [  
    { id: 1, name: 'Location A' },  
    { id: 2, name: 'Location B' },  
    { id: 3, name: 'Location C' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Location D' }
]

Rooms = [  
    { id: 1, name: 'Room A1' },  
    { id: 2, name: 'Room A2' },  
    { id: 3, name: 'Room A3' },  
    { id: 4, name: 'Room A4' },  
    { id: 5, name: 'Room B1' },  
    { id: 6, name: 'Room B2' },  
    { id: 7, name: 'Room C1' },  
    { id: 8, name: 'Room C2' },  
    { id: 9, name: 'Room C3' },  
    { id: 10, name: 'Room C4' },  
    { id: 11, name: 'Room C5' },  
]   { id: 12, name: 'Room D1' },  
]
```

Sample relations:

- configuration rule 1 should be global and apply to all rooms in all buildings
- configuration rule 2 should be global and apply to all rooms in all buildings
- configuration rule 3 should be applied to building A & B and thereby to all rooms in these buildings
- configuration rule 4 should apply to only  building C
- configuration rule 5 should apply to only room C3
- configuration rule 6 should apply to only room D1

So that following function can be executed with:
configRuleByIdAppliesTo(1) => return a result for global
configRuleByNameAppliesTo('hasInternet') => return a result for the config rules 2, 3 and 4 with the applied config rules.
getConfigRulesForBuilding({ id: 2, name: 'Location B' }) => return a result for with config for the building and rooms.

Comment: What's wrong with having three different types of configuration rules (global, building, room)?

Comment: I guess that would be fine, but how would this be represented in the entities / relations and database?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the types. You only have one hierarchical type. lets call it Room

```
Room
{
  Id //use a guid
  parentId //null = its the world
} 

configurationRoomMapping
{
  ConfigurationId
  RoomId
}
```

Now if you want to find out if a rule applies to particular room you just check the mapping for the room and then loop up that rooms parents checking each in turn, building the list of configurations as you go.

Comment: I like this idea, but I only have 3 levels (Global, Building and Room) and level 1 should be a building and 2 should be a room. I forgot to mention that rooms and buildings have different properties. Also a building can't be a child of a building. How would this be representated and enforced in this hierarchy?

Comment: add a "type" property globe, building, room add more tables using the same id for the extra data put the rules in your repository object etc etc.

Comment: Could you extend your answer with an example of this? And how to guard the types to the corresponding levels?

Comment: I'm not going to write out all the code for you. if you can explain which bit you think is problematic?

Comment: So I would add  type = Global | Building | Room to the a Location entity (in your example Room entity), correct? 
How could I enforce that a level 1 object needs to be a building and a level 2 object needs can only be a Room?

Comment: with `if` statements? sorry to be snarky but i dont understand where you are coming from on this

Comment: @ErwinvanHoof: you accepted this overgeneralized and less readable approach, which would make only sense if you had more than just buildings and rooms, but multiple levels? Really? Do yourself a favor and don't implement it this way.

Comment: totally going to get a "no power on 4th floor" situation before the project is over and my genius design will save your ass!

Comment: I will provide my final solution in an answer. But Ewans approach makes more sense because its easily extendable if a new level is needed or a new entity needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I finally went with the following solution (extending on @Ewan answer).

This gives me, imho flexibility to add new levels and types without much hustle. Without opening the classes for modifications, I just need to add a class for the new type.

```typescript
Location {
    id: number;
    parentId: number | null;
}

Global {
    location: Location; 
}

Building {
    id: number; 
    location: Location; 
    name: string;
    stories: number;
    builddate: date:
}

Room {
    id: number; 
    location: Location; 
    name: string;
    dimensions: {
        height: number;
        width: number;
        depth: number;
    }
}

ConfigurationRule {
    id: number; 
    key: string;
    value: any;
}

ConfigurationLocationMapping {
  configurationId: number;
  locationId: number;
}
```

Please let me know what you think of this solution?

Comment: you wont know what type to instantiate from your database when you load them. if you want to extend my design with type, just add "type" to the base class and inherit from it.